# forwardRef with typescript React

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to use the forwardRef in typescript React to access a child state. I've followed examples online but many are for javascript. I'm getting compiler errors with this.

This is the simplest version I can come up with and the compiler doesn't like the console log. It says ref.current may be undefined, so I've used some && logic but now it says getMyState() does not exist on type 'never'. I've also looked up that error as I've seen it before but don't understand it in this context.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  console.log(ref.current && ref.current.getMyState());
  return(
    <>
    <Child ref={ref}/>
    </>
  );
  
}
const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState('hello');
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({getMyState: () => {return item}}), [item]);

  return (
    <>
    bob
    </>
  );
})
```

Note: I've read the React docs, my use case is a valid one for forwardRef.

Why am I getting this error and how do I extract the state from the child?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `type` for the `ref` with the form of functions you expose in the `Child` component.

Try like below.

```
type ChildHandle = {
  getMyState: () => string | null;
};

const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [item, setItem] = useState("hello");
  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      getMyState: () => {
        return item;
      }
    }),
    [item]
  );

  return <>bob</>;
});

const Parent = () => {
  const ref = useRef<ChildHandle>();
  console.log(ref.current && ref.current.getMyState());
  return (
    <>
      <Child ref={ref} />
    </>
  );
};
```

#### Example of using the handle of Child within Parent

[image: Edit React Typescript (forked)]

Comment: @user2956284, check this out !!

Comment: This worked great thanks. Although I didn't expect the reference to be affected when the child is called multiple times.

e.g. if I pass in a reference to child once and then call child 2 more times but without passing in a reference, the reference still changes. I wonder if there is a way around this as I'd like a separate reference for each instance.

I can still work with this though :)

Comment: what do you mean by "call child 2 more times"? If you create two Child elements then you should pass two separate refs to them.

Comment: My bad. I'm too tired and left in some code where it shouldn't be.

Comment: Is there a way to make it not also spit out undefineds? It's working great, but my refs quickly turn to undefined. I could work around it but wondering if there is a way to do it inside the return statement of the child.

Comment: The console log in the parent component in the first render is expected to log undefined. But if you turn it into a function where you click on a button to log the value then it would be fine. You have to check ref.current is null or not.